# How do I tar files and put them in a list with gitbash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, git-bash

I am using Git bash and wanted to archive my files with the "tar" function in git Bash.

[image: Here is an exemplary folder]
As you can see, these files have dates in their name and I want to tar all dates in separate tar files.
The result would be in this case that I have 2 tar files with 2 different dates.

My idea was to "find" the 6 digits in these files with `find iname "jo* | \d\d\d\d\d\d | sort | tar -czvf testarchive.zip ~/test/targetfolder` and then tar them. But then, I have to put the first found dates in a list, tar them until the date changes and then put the second datefiles in a list and so on...

Since I have no experience with bash and scripting, I dont know how to solve this problem. I would be very happy for help. I was not able to find a solution in the internet yet..

P.S. I am not sure if git bash is Linux/Unix or a different script language or if it is just Git bash, so sorry if i didnt meet up all the requirements.

Comment: Bash is Bash everywhere. It is commonly bundled with the version control system Git on Windows because the native command shells on Windows are horrible and/or incompatible between Windows versions, but it's not part of or dependent on Git per se.

Comment: The `.zip` extension is usually only used for PKzip and related archives, which are in completely a different format than `tar` archives. The customary extension for gzip (not zip!) compessed tar files is `.tar.gz`, or `.tgz` on legacy systems where only three letters were available for the file extension. If you want to create `.zip` archives, look for the `zip` utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```sh
for pat in jo[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*; do
    tail=${pat#jo[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
    head=${pat%"$tail"}
    date=${head#jo}
    # If this tarball exists, skip
    if [ -e "$date.tar.gz" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    # Else, tar this date
    tar czvf "$date.tar.gz" "jo$date"*
done
```

It's unclear where or how you hoped `~/test/targetfolder` would be used. If that's where the files are, perhaps just `cd` there before running this. If that's where you want the tar files to be created, put it before `"$date.tar.gz"` everywhere in the above.

The parameter expansions `${variable#pattern}` and `${variable%pattern}` produce the value of `$variable` with, repectively, any prefix or suffix match on `pattern` removed.

Comment: Thanks. this worked. And I also have declared my target folder successfully. But I am wondering what these lines are doing? You wrote they are producing the value of $variable but I didnt understand it that well.
1. I thought that "#" is for commenting and you put it in line 2 right after pat
2. What does "pat%" return in line 3?
3. What is "-e" doing in the if clause? Does it mean exist?

Comment: They are special inside `${...}`. For a simple example, `echo "${HOME#/}"` prints your home directory with the first `/` removed (the prefix matches a literal slash, and the variable normally begins with a slash, so the prefix matches, and is removed).  And yes, the `-e` opttion for `[` checks for file existence. Maybe try https://explainshell.com/ if you can't make sense of the manuals.

Comment: I cant find anywhere, what the "%" stands for? I know that "pat#jo" means "pat without jo*" but what does "pat%tail" mean ?

Comment: If you have a variable `$pat` whose value is `foobarbaz`, then `${pat#foo}` produces `barbaz` and `$(pat%baz}` produces `foobar` (while of course `${pat#other}` still produces `foobarbaz` because `other` does not match the beginning of the value, so nothing is stripped). This is called "parameter expansion"; see [the reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for more details,

Comment: Removing a prefix and then removing the result from the suffix produces the portion which was removed at the beginning; so `${pat%"$tail"}` trims off the thing we just extracted into `tail`, and what remains is the prefix which we trimmed off the tail from. We take this detour because we can predict the length of the prefix but not the length of the suffix; if the pattern allowed for more complex operations, like regular expressions, this could be more succinct (but probably on the whole harder to understand and maintain).

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I'd build an associative array of unique dates, then `tar` each set that matched.

```
$: echo jo* # I made some similar local files
jo02042018ab jo02042018cd jo10112018ab jo10112018cd jo10112018ef
```

Filenames aren't exact, but close enough to make the point.

```
$: declare -A dateLst # create an *associative* array, keys are dates
```

An *associative* array uses strings as indexes (even if they are numbers).

```
$: for f in jo[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?? # for each file
>  do dateLst["${f//[^0-9]/}"]=1                         # assert date as a key
>  done
```

`dateLst[somekey]=1` creates a unique `somekey` in `dateLst`.
`${f//[^0-9]/}` removes all non-numerals from the filename, leaving only the date. (This will probably work fine even if they actually have `.txt` filename extensions, though you'll need to edit the glob in the `for` statement.)
So, `dateLst["${f//[^0-9]/}"]=1` sets the date from the file as a key in the lookup table. If it already exists, it just sets it again.

We now have a table of unique dates we can use to create tarballs.

```
$: for t in "${!dateLst[@]}"; do echo tar -cvzf $t.tgz jo$t*; done
tar -cvzf 10112018.tgz jo10112018ab jo10112018cd jo10112018ef
tar -cvzf 02042018.tgz jo02042018ab jo02042018cd
```

`${!dateLst[@]}` is the keys from the table, so this loops over the distinct dates and `echo`s the `tar` command to create each tarball. `jo$t*` lists all matching files to be included in that archive. Remove the `echo` to execute the commands.

Comment: I tried this step by step.. But it does not work. It tells me  "tar: jo090909090909*: Cannont stat: no such file or directory

Comment: Has to be run in the directory with the source files.